# Setting up Dual-display with seperate Images

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, desktop-customization

How can I set a Different background on each monitor when using dual-display?
Currently I have One background and it sets it as both Monitors backgrounds.

Comment: Windows 7. The tile option makes like four of the same image on each monitor.

Comment: Use a picture that matches the combined res of both displays.  So if you have 2x 1920x1080 then have a picture that is 3840x1080, even if you resize it to get there. then try and tile that.

Comment: About everything is covered best in this Q&A http://superuser.com/questions/491112/how-can-i-set-a-dual-display-single-background-when-my-primary-display-is-on-th?rq=1

Comment: I read that and didnt seem to find what I needed but thanks.

Comment: Yes it is mostly about alignment of monitors that are 2-1 setup (not a dupe of this) but it has a lot of usefull total data. The last answer (with the worst votes) is pretty good, then the software recommendation you will see there.

Answer (score 0):

I used a program called "UltraMon" to do this in Windows 7.
Besides being able to manage backgrounds it also helped me running games on other than my primary screen.